# Background processes for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, irc

I am looking to create an IRC app for wp8. There are already a few good clients out there, but they all share a common issue: Keeping an open connection while users are using other apps. From my research, I know there are two types of background agents available from the wp8 SDK (periodic and resource-intensive). 
I am sure that this is possible to do, given the fact that there are internet radio apps that maintain an open internet connection in the background.
My thoughts so far include scheduling periodic updates to the app every few seconds or so, but this doesn't seem like a viable way of doing things.
Can anyone provide insight as to how internet radio apps work on the wp8 os, or an alternative way to going about solving this issue?
Edit: This project is in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My thoughts so far include scheduling periodic updates to the app every few seconds or so

Not possible. IF your app is not the foreground app, you can only use Periodic Tasks which run only every 30 mins. Thats the reason no app like you describe exists. It's a limitation in the OS and it is by design, in order to keep battery consumption low.

Comment: They work because those are background audio playback which is allowed. Other than that you are limited to the background tasks I'm mentioning in my answer. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: But when does the actual downloading/streaming of the song occur? Because as I understand them, that process happens in the background. (thanks for your answer, I'm just trying to get a feel for how things work)

Comment: I don't know how pandora works, it's not available in my country. I suspect that the download of the stream happens under the lock screen, while the app is the foreground app, or if it still continues to stream when you navigate away from it, they might have made a deal with microsoft in order to have more privileges to the OS, bypassing the security and the battery saving model on it. I haven't really touched background audio playback, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: All right, thanks. I believe I've come up with a (pretty hacky) solution to my specific problem. Once I've done some testing I'll report back.

Comment: Just remember that as long as you stay in the app, you can do anything. The limitations begin when you navigate away from it.